# Partial views don't return all data that

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm experiencing a strange problem with a form created with Razor in asp.net MVC 3 project. My main view is strongly typed of type :

```
@model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>
```

I have four partial views which are rendered one after another creating table. Here is the code of the main view...

```
<div id="drawForm">
    <table border="1">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (Model[i].ContentTypeId == 1)
            {
                headerModel.Add(Model[i]);
            }
            if (Model[i].ContentTypeId == 2)
            {
                drawModel.Add(Model[i]);
            }
            if (Model[i].ContentTypeId == 3)
            {
                bodyModel.Add(Model[i]);
            }
            if (Model[i].ContentTypeId == 4)
            {
                footerModel.Add(Model[i]);
            }
        }
        @Html.Partial("_PartialHeadear", headerModel)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialDrawing", drawModel)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialBody", bodyModel)
        @Html.Partial("_PartialFooter", footerModel)
    </table>
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</div>
```

I should get 20 maybe 25 or even 30 records back in my controller :

```
public ActionResult ActionMethodName(List<MCS_DocumentFields> collection)
        {
            var test = collection;
            List<MCS_Documents> model = DocumentService.All().ToList();
            return View("Index", model);
        }
```

But what really happen is that I get only the data from the first partial view. And most of the time I get exactly 10 records. I tried to change the order of rendering of the partial view and I always get the whole data from the first partial view up to 10 records depending on which is the second. I thought there is something with this number 10, so I made a test rendering a partial view with 30 records and when I rendered it first I got 30 records back. So it's not limited to 10, but then if say my first partial has 2 records and my second partial has 12 records I get back 10 records any this way I get only 1 record from the 2 records partial and 10 records from the 12 records partial. All this seems very random excluding this number ten.

Here are two of my partials just to see how I'm dealing with them :

```
@model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center">
                <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/" + Model[i].FieldValue)" alt="Logo" />
                @Html.HiddenFor(d => d[i].FieldValue)
                @Html.HiddenFor(d => d[i].QuestionText)
                @Html.HiddenFor(d => d[i].Id)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

and this one has more logic in it:

```
@model List<DataAccess.MCS_DocumentFields>
@{
    int headerCol = 0;    
}
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
                if (headerCol == 0)
                { 
                        @:<tr>
                    }
                    if (Model[i].MCS_Fields.FieldTypeId == 98)
                    {                       
                        <td colspan="2">
                            @*<img src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/" + Model[i].FieldValue)" alt="Logo" />*@
                            @Html.DisplayFor(y => y[i].FieldValue)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].FieldValue)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].Id)
                        </td>
                        ++headerCol;
                    }
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model[i].FieldValue) && Model[i].MCS_Fields.FieldTypeId != 98)
                    {
                        <td colspan="2">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(y => y[i].QuestionText)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].QuestionText)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].FieldValue)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].Id)
                        </td> 
                        ++headerCol;
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        <td colspan="2">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(y => y[i].QuestionText)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].QuestionText)
                            :
                            @Html.DisplayFor(y => y[i].FieldValue)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].FieldValue)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(y => y[i].Id)
                        </td> 
                        ++headerCol;
                    }

                     if (headerCol == 2)
                     {
                         headerCol = 0;
                        @:</tr>
                     }
}
```

Any ideas about this strange behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: Two strange things I've noticed: (1) Is your action *really* named `ActionMethodName`? (2) On your main view `for`, you're testing if `ContentTypeId == 2` for header *and* for draw. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the first - yeah this is my name (test name of course) second is mistake it should be 1 and 2 I'll fix it.

Comment: Can you check `Model.Count` property?

Comment: Yeap - it holds all the records, I even debugged the whole `for` statement so each instance holds the records it needs, also - all this is rendered and I can see it in the browser, but can't get back the data, or the whole data to be more specific.

Comment: 1. Your model in the controller is `MCS_Documents`.  Everywhere else it is `MCS_DocumentFields`.  Typo?  2. What are headerModel, drawModel et al. defined as?  3. Where are you only seeing 1 or 10 records?  In the partial view?  4. Why have all that logic in your view?  Create a view model with four collections, fill them in your controller and pass that as your model to the view.

Comment: My controller takes one argument of type `MCS_DocumentFields` and I return `MCS_Documents` to another view. The 10 records are in my controller method `var test`. I don't know what to say about the view model, it's my first asp.net mvc application so I guess lack of experience explains a lot of this.